# IonTabs params doesn't work when working with Promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working with Tabs and I want to load some data from my storage in my `tabs.ts` and then I want to transfer the data in my tabs pages (I've got 3 tabs). I pass the data with `[rootParams]` for every tab. My problem is that the default tab (the tab which the application start) doesn't display anything. I attach you some code:

constructur of `tabs.ts`

```
this.storage.get(key).then(value => this.list = value);
```

Html of my tabs page

```
<ion-tab [root]="mypage" [rootParams]="list"></ion-tab>
```

In the constructor of `mypage.ts` I do this:

```
constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
  this.list = this.navParams.data;
}
```

In mypage html I loop on the list with a simple `*ngFor`, but I don't see anything. I think the problem is that the first page is loaded before the Promise of the storage object gets the results. I don't know how to solve this. In the other tabs the trick works like a charm, but because I load them a few time later than the first tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ngAfterViewInit()`. It will execute after the promise of the storage

```
ngAfterviewInit(){
  this.list = this.navParams.data;

}
```

Comment: It works for the second and the third tab, but not for the first one.